# Why does triggering Azure Function from Logic Apps return "Bad Request"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My Azure Function works well if run from the browser
https://examplefunction.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger-Java?name=testEUR.txt&code=mycode

I configured the function to run as a stage in "Logic Apps" - hard-coding the "name" parameter for testing purposes

[image]

But then I get "Bad Request" when running the function via logic apps

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by adding `"authlevel":"anonymous"` to function.json which is in under site/wwwroot/examplefunction

[Instructions to set the authentication level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#set-up-anonymous-authentication-in-your-function) are as follows

1. select **Platform** features. Under **Development tools**, select **Advanced tools (Kudu)**.
2. On the Kudu website's title bar, from the **Debug Console menu**, select **CMD**.
3. After the next page appears, from the folder list, select **site > wwwroot > examplefunction**.
4. Open the **function.json** file for editing.
5. In the bindings object, check whether the **authLevel** property exists. If the property exists, set the property value to **anonymous**. Otherwise, add that property and set the value.

Once this has been done, then in the Request body of the logic app, just putting `"testEUR.txt"` works

Obviously, a better answer would be one that does not seem to apparently disable authentication.